# App Widget not listed in google now launcher widget list in Nexus 5 (Android 5.1.1)

Tags: android, widget, android-launcher, nexus-5, app-launcher

I have an app which has a widget along with it. It works fine for all devices except Nexus 5. The widget is not listed in widget list of Nexus 5's google now launcher. I have tested installing the app on Nexus 7 (Android 5.1.1) with same google now launcher and the widget shows up in the list.

I have seen a similar [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159337) filed for the google now launcher, but here they mentioned that on the device reboot the widget was showing up. Strangely though even this doesn't work me. I have installed another custom launcher(Nova launcher) and tested this scenario and my widget shows up without any problem.

Here is my code below for my config xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="350dp" android:minHeight="133dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="3600000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/ana_app_widget"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/ana_app_widget">
    </appwidget-provider>
```

Here is my manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".AppWidget">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/ana_app_widget_info" />
</receiver>

<service
    android:name=".StackWidgetService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"
    android:exported="false">

</service>
```

Any help would be appreciated.